# Submit form (and disable button) in dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have a one-page design, where I set a main div to hold and show the current "page" content (with jquery)

Then I have this in a js file:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#kontaktform", function(){

        $theform = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: "kontakt_val.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            data: $theform.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if (!data OR data=="ok") {
                    // AJAX ERROR OR OK: Continue to php validation
                    $("input[type=submit]",$theform).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $theform.unbind("submit").submit();
                } else {
                    $("#jserrors").html('<p class="error">' + data + '</p>');
                    $("#jserrors").slideDown(150);
                }
            },
                error: function(e) {
                    // AJAX ERROR: continue to php validation
                    $("input[type=submit]", $theform).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $theform.unbind("submit").submit();
                }
        });

    return false;

});
```

$theform.unbind("submit").submit(); does not seem to submit the form

I'm thinking, it's because the form is in content that is dynamically added with js/jquery

How to fix this?

Comment: why do you wanna submit the form after the ajax call is successful?

Comment: you are unbinding the submit event then how could you submit?

Comment: @AminJafari Maybe I'm not going to do that. (I'm re-using some code I use for other website, when more php validation was needed).

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar So I can't submit it?

Comment: $theform.unbind("submit").submit(); works when used on form that is not inside dynamically added content

Comment: You should do the "unbind" with off(). Maybe it helps

Comment: @zhonk : off() instead of unbind() you mean?

Comment: @mowgli: yes, with the same selector and the same handler(put your handler function out and give it a name)

Comment: $theform.off("submit").submit(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
document.forms["kontaktform"].submit();
```

Don't know how to do it Jquery style though